# Can I use wysiwyg text editör in Adobe LC ES2 while a Pdf Page design period

Tags: adobe, flex3

I want to add a wysiwyg text editör in Adobe LC Es2 ?

regards
bk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the answer,
http://forums.adobe.com/message/2855457#2855457